# regarding a limit: explicit explanation required

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives

We have, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{p}}{n^{p+1}} = \frac{1}{p+1} \forall 
p\in \mathbb{N}$$

And that is alright, but I am not quite sure for $p\in \mathbb{R}$, my question is, is it true for $p\in \mathbb{R}$?

I've tried calculating the value of this limit in Symbolab Online Calculator, putting $p =some$ $fraction$ $number$, but it shows $0$ as answer. The screenshot of this case is attached herewith.

[[image: for <span class=]$p\in \mathbb{N}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ1qq.png)
And
[image]

Can someone provide me with the approach or even hint to prove or disprove the above mentioned figure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the $5.5$ example, the summand is $5.5$ rather than $k^{5.5}$. It seems you made a typo entering the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true for any $p> -1$.  It actually is a Riemann sum:
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{p}}{n^{p+1}}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^{p}}{n^p}$$
for the function $f(x)=x^p$, with bounds $0$ and $1$, therefore it converges to
$$\int_0^1\!\! x^p\,\mathrm dx=\frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}\Biggr\vert_0^1=\frac 1{p+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let use [Stoltz-Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) to obtain

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^{p}-\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{p}}{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}=\frac{(n+1)^p}{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}$$